# wxpython paint event infinite loop

Tags: wxpython, paint, infinite-loop

I would like to draw some simple drawings (lines, circles, etc.) on panel in wxpython. I modified an example code I found somewhere. It works fine, but just until I minimize the window or switch to another window and back. Then it starts repainting in infinite loop.

Should this even happen? If not, is there any way to prevent the infinite loop?

One solution I found was using wx.Timer, but it just caused same loop with adjustable intervals.

```
import math

import wx

class DrawPanel(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title='Drawing on panel')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.OnDraw)

    def OnDraw(self,event=None):
        self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.dc.Clear()
        self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK,1.5))
        i0 = 1
        for i in range(2,1000,1):
            i = i/10.0
            self.dc.DrawLine(i0,200*math.sin(i0/10)+200,
                        i,200*math.sin(i/10)+200)
            i0 = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aplication = wx.App()
    ram = DrawPanel(parent=None)
    ram.Show()
    aplication.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `OnDraw` create local variable `dc` instead of using attribute (`dc` instead of `self.dc`).

Comment: I made dc atribute of the class so it could be accesed by multiple methods. If its cannot be attribute I tried to create multiple drawings overlapping each other and the result was the same. Guess I just have to do all the drawing in one method

Comment: You could always add a parameter `dc` to these methods and call them from the `OnDraw` :) The DC should only be created inside EVT_PAINT handler so you really shouldn't call the method `OnPaint` manually (why the default parameter?).

Comment: Just tried that, but it did the same infinite loop. Maybe I could use multiple methods for preparation for the drawing, but do the actual drawing in one method. Thanks for help

Comment: I dont want to call the method manually, its just when I want to draw something more complicated, one method is too clumsy. By default parameter I guess you mean event=None - I have no idea why its there (stil too noob for that :).

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant :). You could split drawing by calling some methods after `dc.Clear`, eg. `self.drawFirst(dc)` then `self.drawSecond(dc)`. Where `def drawFirst(self, dc)` just draws original stuff (setting pen, drawing in the loop) and `drawSecond` something more.